# How to destroy old thread when the activity recreated in android?

Tags: android, multithreading

I m creating an application using thread.When the activity created thread will start but when i re-create the activity new thread is running and old thread is also running. so i want to destroy old thread.

Answer (score 2):

You never destroy a thread.  Doing so would leave the system in an unknowable state which may be deadlocked.  A thread needs to end itself, as that's the only way it can be sure to be done cleanly. The correct answer is one of these things (and which one depends on circumstances of your program):

1)Don't recreate the activity.  If this is from a configuration change (like rotation), tell Android not to do that via onConfigChange in the manifest.

2)In onDestroy, set a flag on the thread object.  Have the thread periodically check the flag and end itself.  This way it can be done cleanly.  In this case you need to code the Thread defensively to not do anything harmful, you have to more or less assume 2 instances can be running.  If the Thread is really an AsyncTask, you need to check if its Activity is valid before accessing UI components in onPostExecute.

3)Use a Loader type mechanism with either the build in LoaderManager or a roll your own version, attempting to use the same thread without restarting it.

Number 2 is tricky but assured to work.  1 and 3 are easier, but not always possible.

Comment: you haven't mentioned `thread.interrupt()`. Why? Is it bad way to kill a thread?

Comment: Basically interrupt is method 2. It's fine to use that, just understand that it isn't the same as stopping the thread immediately, it cause exceptions that need to be handled, and you need to check for isInterrupted in the thread